# How i can apply rails sort_by on associations attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sorting

i have these associations

```
   class Job
     has_many :job_applications
   end 

   def JobApplication
     belongs_to :job
     has_one :vote_count
   end

   def VoteCount
     #attribute counts  And counts can be 4,5,1,2,6...
     belongs_to :job_application
   end
```

Now i want to sort like

```
      @job = 1  #id = 1

      job_applications = @job.job_applications.sort_by!{|a| a.vote.counts}
```

I need to include all job applications and if there was no vote association for job application it should be 0. But i have nil exception.

Any help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should handle nil vote association the following way:

```
  job_applications = @job.job_applications.sort_by!{|a| a.try(:vote).try(:counts) || 0}
```

Comment: You can multiply the value by -1:  `job_applications = @job.job_applications.sort_by!{|a| -1*(a.try(:vote).try(:counts) || 0)}`

Comment: job_applications = @job.job_applications.sort_by!{|a| a.try(:vote).try(:counts) || 0}.reverse                              it will impact on performance